# Creating vertical line which vertically extends over entire webpage

Tags: html, css, height, line

I have text and want to give the text a left and right border which vertically extends over the entire webpage. This is my html

```
<div id="vLine">
    <h1>text</h1>
</div>
```

and this is my css

```
#vLine {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
```

Now, even though I set my height to 100%, it still like a tiny 2px gap between the top of the line and the top of the webpage, it stretch over the entire page and connect till the top of the page. Why is this gap there? I am using the chromium browser, and i'm guessing this gap will vary depending on browsers but how do I get rid of this gap completely regardless of the browser?

Comment: Try adding body {margin:0;padding:0;} to the css to take care of the 2px space.

Comment: Hm, I have that, it still doesn't work :/

Comment: How about adding margin:0px;padding:0px; to both your #vLine and change the body to body,html{...}.  Does that work?

Comment: Yea I tried those too but it still didn't work for some reason, I did a negative margin-top for vLine and it worked, I put that down as my answer but yea I swear I was positive that adding the margin: 0px and padding: 0px will work. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm okay so what I tried way,

```
#vLine {
    margin: -10px;
}
```

and it worked, turns out that gap which looked like just 2px was 10px but yea, it fixed it.